# Python3 send requests cookies from previous call

Tags: python-3.x, session, python-requests

I want to resend the initialized cookies from the first call in the second call, so that the session is not changing. This is not working.

Why? And how can I solve it. Sorry, new in python

```
https_url = "www.google.com"
r = requests.get(https_url)
print(r.cookies.get_dict())
#cookie = {id: abc}

response = requests.get(https_url, cookies=response.cookies.get_dict())
print(response.cookies.get_dict())
#cookie = {id: def}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't necessarily doing it wrong with the way you're passing the cookies from the last response to the next request, except that:

1. `"www.google.com"` is not a valid URL.
2. Even you had used `http://www.google.com` as the URL, the cookies returned by Google in such a GET request aren't meant to be session cookies and won't be persistent across requests.
3. You used the variable `r` to receive the returning value from the first `requests.get`, and yet you used `response.cookies` when you make the second `requests.get`. A possible typo?
4. If all of the above are due to your trying to mock up your real code, you should really consider using `requests.Session` to avoid micro-managing session cookies.

Please read [`requests.Session`'s documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) for more details.

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(https_url)
    # cookies from the first s.get are automatically passed on to the second s.get
    r = s.get(https_url)
    ...
```